# how to parallelize a nested for loop with if statements in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, vectorization, parallel-foreach

Heres a sample code that illustrates my problem :

```
for(i  in 1:100) {
    for(j in 1:100)
    { 
       if (A[i] < A[j]) {
            tempMatrix[i, j]  <- foo(val_1[i], val_2[j])
        } else {
            tempMatrix[i, j]  <- foo(val_2[j], val_1[i])
        }
    }
}
```

The above piece of code takes too long to compute, is there a way to parallelize the above?

val_1, val_2, and A are vectors of about 50k elements

Comment: Look into the `plyr` package, the syntax is a bit easier than using standard `apply` family of functions.

Comment: If dead set on parallel `for` loops, take a look at the `foreach` package. You may also be able to replace the outer loop with a parallel apply function, see the `parallel` package for details on those.

Comment: Please consider giving us some sample data to make your question reproducible. For example, give us 10 values for each of `A`, `val_1` and `val_2`. Also, something instead of `foo`; would `min`, `max` or `mean` be suitable?

Comment: Its a complicated function. Lets say its about O(N^2).

Answer (score 0):

Basic vectorization using `ifelse` seems like it gets a 40% speedup by itself:

```
n <- 300
A <- rnorm(n)
val_1 <- rpois(n, 10)
val_2 <- rpois(n, 20)
tempMatrix <- matrix(NA, n, n)
tempMatrix2 <- matrix(NA, n, n)


foo <- function(i, j) if( i %% j == 0) 5 else i


microbenchmark(times=30, orig=
for(i  in 1:n) {
    for(j in 1:n)
    { 
       if (A[i] < A[j]) {
            tempMatrix[i, j]  <- foo(val_1[i], val_2[j])
        } else {
            tempMatrix[i, j]  <- foo(val_2[j], val_1[i])
        }
    }
}
,mapp=
for(j in 1:n) {
  w <- A < A[j]
  x <- ifelse(w, val_1, val_2[j])
  y <- ifelse(w, val_2[j], val_1)
  tempMatrix2[,j] = mapply(foo, x, y)
}
)
all.equal(tempMatrix, tempMatrix2)
```

Yields:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval
 orig 187.449344 191.274325 195.7138641 192.635209 196.705712 220.292461    30
 mapp 116.479130 117.531128 121.5658793 118.779243 123.359916 147.540282    30
```

Raising n to 400 yields:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq        mean      median         uq        max neval
 orig 338.356754 341.815807 351.2388823 345.4547705 357.107122 382.312691    30
 mapp 203.892420 206.377714 209.9775747 208.6823080 210.757181 239.354271    30
```